# How to check if a user just started a new session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, http-headers, http-referer

I want to determine if a user just started a new session in my Rails app. I am currently using HTTP referer to define what a new session is. But I am not sure if this is the correct way. The following code is written in Ruby.

```
if !request.referrer || !request.referrer.start_with?(request.protocol + request.host_with_port)
  # If the user came from another site or came here directly, then we regard it as a new session
else
  # Not a new session
end
```

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085607/knowing-when-a-new-session-starts-in-rails

Comment: What do you mean by "a new session"? They reconnected after having closed their old session, or do they have two simultaneous sessions and you want to limit them to one?

Answer (score 0):

You can store an attribute in the session the first time the user visits. If the attribute is set then you can safely conclude they've visited your website before.

If, however, the attribute is not set then it could mean many things:

- the user is visiting your site for the first time
- the user may have deleted their cookies, and you can't tell that they're returning
- the user may visiting from different browser or on a different device too

This is how you would code it up

```
if session.has_key?(:visited_before)
  # user has visited before
else
  # new user
  session[:visited_before] = true
end
```

You should be wary of

- where the sessions are being stored and memory limitations, but I wouldn't let this stop you from getting started unless it's a high traffic website.
- googlebot and other search engine crawlers, you can detect those in the user agent headers and avoid setting the session.

Comment: The limitation by checking the referrer is you're not able to track a user across multiple visits. eg. a user visits your site, leaves, then comes back again you will treat them as a new user. Although you face the same problem with sessions, you'll be able to track a user for a longer period of time (until they clear their browser history or session expires if you set that)

Comment: I see. But I doesn't want to determine if the user is a new one or not. I want to determine sessions, that is, the "sessions" in Google Analytics. So if the users close the browser and came back again, it should be considered a new session.